# Selenium Webdriver Timeout (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, selenium, debugging, selenium-webdriver, firebug

When scraping data from NASDAQ there are tickers like ACHC that have empty pages. [ACHC Empty Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlOAd.png)

My program iterates through all ticker symbols and when I get to this one it times out because there is no data to grasp. I am trying to figure out a way to check if there is nothing and if so skip the ticker, but continue the loop. The code is pretty long, so Ill post the most relevant part: the beginning of the loop where it opens the page:

```
## navigate to income statement annualy page    
url = url_form.format(symbol, "income-statement")
browser.get(url)

company_xpath = "//h1[contains(text(), 'Company Financials')]"
company = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, company_xpath))).text

annuals_xpath = "//thead/tr[th[1][text() = 'Period Ending:']]/th[position()>=3]"
annuals = get_elements(browser,annuals_xpath)
```

[Here is a pic of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAOvi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium doesn't have a built-in method for determining whether an element exists or not, so the most common thing to do is use a try/except block.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
...
try:
    company = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, company_xpath))).text
except TimeoutException:
   continue
```

This should keep the loop going without crashing, assuming that `continue` works as expected with your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like `requests` or `urllib` to scrape that web page and check if what you need is there. These libraries are much faster than Selenium because they just fetch the source of the page. If there are particular tags or structures like tables, etc. that you're looking for, you should take a look at `beautifulsoup` which you can use with `requests` to identify very specific parts of the page.